# Merge List of Adjectives and Nouns with All Possible Combinations (Ruby, Python, or PHP)

Tags: php, python, ruby, file

I have a list of adjectives.txt and a list of nouns.txt that I've spent many hours collecting. I'd like to combine the lists using every possible adjective-noun combination.

***Example:***

**Adjectives**

- angry
- dirty
- frozen

**Nouns**

- car
- rock
- kitten

**Results**

- angrycar
- angryrock
- angrykitten
- dirtycar
- dirtyrock
- dirtykitten
- frozencar
- frozenrock
- frozenkitten

I can use Ruby, Python or PHP with relative confidence. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show a little from your file

Comment: **cough** nested loop **cough**

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: Introductory Computer Science class? You are supposed to solve this on your own, my friend. Computer Science is *all about solving problems*. If this has you stumped then you can just as well drop out of the class right now; you will not get far.

Comment: Not trying to pass a class, just find a domain name. There's no textmechanic.com like site that will do this for me. Just wanted to solve a problem, not learn programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a *Ruby* way :

```
noun_text = <<END
angry
dirty
frozen
END

adj_text = <<END
car
rock
kitten
END

File.write('f1',noun_text)
File.write('f2',adj_text)
```

collecting the lines from the file `"f1"`( which contains all noun words) and file `"f2"`( which contains all the adjective words). As I used [`IO::readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines), which gives all the lines as an *Array*. Thus `noun_ary` holds all noun words and `adj_ary` holds the adjective words as an array.

```
noun_ary = File.readlines('f1').map(&:strip)
adj_ary = File.readlines('f2').map(&:strip)
```

Now I used [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-product) method, to get *all combinations of elements from both arrays.*

```
result = noun_ary.product(adj_ary).map(&:join)
```

Now I used [`IO::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-open) method to open the file `f3`, with *write* method(as you can see `"w"`). Now inside the block, I called [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each) method, to get the each result element, and write them into the file `f3`, using [`IO::puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-puts) method.

```
File.open('f3','w') do |file|
  result.each { |line| file.puts line }
end
```

Now, I opened the result file `f3` again using `IO::open`, which will give an [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html) object. Now [`IO::each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-each) method to gee the each line from `f3` and prints it using [`Kernel#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) method.

```
File.open('f3','r').each do |line|
  puts line
end
# >> angrycar
# >> angryrock
# >> angrykitten
# >> dirtycar
# >> dirtyrock
# >> dirtykitten
# >> frozencar
# >> frozenrock
# >> frozenkitten
```

Comment: Great. Now how would I print this to a .txt file? This worked great.

Comment: @ZachBrowne see this `File.open('f3','w')` part.

Comment: I will explain each line of code, once I will be back after 15 mins

Comment: @ZachBrowne I am done1 hope you now can go ahead with explanations

Comment: @ZachBrowne Then change `noun_ary.product(adj_ary).map(&:join)` to `adj_ary.product(noun_ary).map(&:join)`.. I have seen it reverse way, sorry :-)

Comment: I just did ruby combine.rb > combine.txt. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Instead of `File.open('f3').each` consider using `File.foreach('f3')`. It does the same thing. If using `open(...)`, it's a good habit to always use the mode parameter, even for the default behavior. It's more obvious what is happening when it's `open('some/file', 'r')` and `open('some/file', 'w')`.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree with you. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

In Python

```
>>> adj = ['a', 'b']
>>> nouns = ['C', 'D']
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product(adj, nouns))
[('a', 'C'), ('a', 'D'), ('b', 'C'), ('b', 'D')]
```

That gives you pairs that then you can join/print/whatever

Answer (score 2):

Save nouns and adjectives to array, then loop values and print. Use PHP.

```
$nouns = file('nouns.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$adjectives =  file('adjectives.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($adjectives as $adjective) {
   foreach($nouns as $noun) {
      echo $adjective, $noun, '<br />';
   }
}
```

**`file()` Note:** I'm assuming that every word is on its own line, if you use some different style for imploding words, use `explode()` instead for converting file to array.

[Demo!](http://codepad.org/gDGpyjV6)

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
import itertools

output = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(adjectives, nouns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print [x+y for x in adjectives for y in nouns]
```

in python

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for adjective in adjectiveList:
    for noun in nounList:
         result.append(adjective + noun)
```

more python